# How do we tell the purpose of a text (paper, article) if it is not stated explicitly?

Tags: reading

Recently, I've been teaching myself Academic writing to enhance my critical thinking and English (I'm an ESL student). Following the textbook (A sequence for Academic Writing), I was tasked with reading [this article](https://techfinancials.co.za/2015/12/04/external-enhancements-of-memory-may-soon-go-high-tech/) and stating the purpose of the author.

In the textbook, they said that the author [she] was trying to urge caution regarding brain implants that enhance memory. What I don't understand is how they even came up with this statement while the author does not explicitly state it. Did they make use of the tone, styles or anything else in the text or was it just experience after reading so many texts.

Thank you so much

Comment: The question in the body here does not match the question in the headline. However, it is probably off-topic in either case.
If you are asking in general how to understand the unstated purpose of a text, that *might* be appropriate on Academia, but might be better on a language-related SE.
If you are asking specifically how this author interpreted this text, then it's off-topic as it is about a specific reseach area rather than academia in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fellow ESL student here! Based on my previous academic writing courses, I've been taught that one way to gather the purpose of an article is to ask yourself "Why is the author writing this article" and "Why is this article written this way"?

Let's take a look at the concluding paragraphs, as these are the paragraphs which are supposed to restate the main ideas. In the following paragraphs:

> Developing technology for total recall may sound wonderful and time-saving for improving daily living. Never forget an appointment, never spend precious minutes looking for misplaced keys, perhaps never even need a calendar to remember important events. And, of course, an implantable brain chip would be a huge boon for those whose memories have been destroyed by disease or injury. But there’s a hitch to total recall that doesn’t allow us as individuals and as a society to forget.
> Perfect memory engenders stasis – the legacy of any failures (personal or in others) won’t be allowed to fade and therefore we cannot move past them. Forgetting allows for new beginnings and for personal and societal healing and forgiveness. It is critical for a war veteran to advance past a traumatizing event from the battlefield, or a spouse with hurt feelings to be able to let go of that experience to repair a relationship. We all need to let some memories go; it’s part of the process that allows us to appreciate the proverbial forest of our existence while not getting too bogged down with the trees of our daily lives.
>
> For better or worse, technology for not ever forgetting may be here
> sometime soon. Whatever form this imagined external memory enhancement
> takes, it will be interesting to see how a new way of remembering
> changes us in return.
>
> Perhaps some of us may have to add one more thing to our list –
> remember to forget.

the author states that while there are some benefits to brain implants providing permanent memories, there are also drawbacks.

Note that:

- The author doesn't say that these implants should be banned altogether
- The author acknowledges that there are upsides to these implants, but also writes about the downsides in this article.

*What are the motivations for these points?*

One answer is that the author is trying to warn readers (i.e. **urge caution**) that while brain implants are useful, the drawbacks should not be ignored.

In summary, yes, gathering the main purpose of a text can be attributed to experience, but more importantly it's about making good inferences. Put yourself in the shoes of the author, and think "what am I trying to tell others?"

I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for the probing '*why*', and for *experience*, and putting one in the shoes of the author